# Sum of only consecutive number

Tags: r

I have an array which like

```
a <- c(1,2,3,7,8,14,17,18)
```

I want to sum only consecutive numbers, I want answer like this using R.

> "6, 15, 14, 35"

I shall really appreciate for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tapply` to group by consecutive values,

```
tapply(a, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(a) != 1)), sum)
# 0  1  2  3 
# 6 15 14 35
```